# minimize a function using SGD

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I have to solve the following exercice :

$$ min   ||Ax - y||_2 + ||x||_2^2$$with respect to x, where A ∈ $R^{q×p}$, x ∈ $R^p$ and y ∈ $R^q$. Use stochastic gradient descent.

My first question is how do you solve that if q and p have different values.

the function is is convex so we can use SGD. We have :  $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = A - 2x$$

and SGD goes:
for nb of iterations:
    $$x_{k+1} = x_k - learningRate ×  \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} $$

Is that correct? 
How can I implement a simulation of this problem? After creating x, y vectors and Matrix A with the correct dimensions and initialise them with random values, I would need a loss function (like MSE). How do I define it? 
 Thanks!

Comment: Your gradient isn't correct.  Chances are that you want to use $\| Ax-y \|_{2}^{2}$ in the objective.

Comment: @BrianBorchers thanks. This can't be solved if the first term is not squarred? what would be the problem?

Comment: how about dimensions? does it work i p and q are different?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem were instead

$$ 
\min_x   ||Ax - y||_2^2 + ||x||_2^2
$$

we will then have

$$
\min_x x^t (A^t A + I)x -2 y^t A x + y^ty
$$

so after derivation regarding $x$

$$
2x^t(A^t A+I)-2y^t A = 0
$$

and solving

$$
x^t = y^t A (A^t A + I)^{-1}
$$